# How to print a graph with data from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I got my data with `.value_counts()` and now I want to plot that and show the graph but with no success...

Here is my code:

```
new_list = df[['StudentID', ' Duration']]

new_list[' Duration'].value_counts().plot(kind='hist')
```

The code finishes without errors but my graph doesn't show? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `matplotlib.pyplot` library to show the graph.

this is example code.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

...
new_list = df[['StudentID', ' Duration']]
new_list[' Duration'].value_counts().plot(kind='hist')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that we've created the plot, we need to display it, so we'll use the matplotlib.pyplot library's plt.show() method to see the graph.